# Read a specific line in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io, fgets

I'm learning PHP. I want to find the fifth line from a file:

```
hello world
hey world
hi world
goodbye cruel world
hello user
hey user
...
```

I have `reader.php`:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("intro.txt");
$count = 5;
if ($handle) {
    while (--$count > 0) {
        fgets($handle);
    }
    echo fgets($handle);
    if ( !feof($handle)) {
        echo "Unexpected Exception";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

The file should be opened and `$count` is iterated through to move through `--$count` lines, so we can read the `$count`-eth line. I don't have a debugger to run.

But nothing is getting printed. Why?

Comment: Maybe it's simplier to use `file`?

Comment: @u_mulder I just looked up the manual for `file`: Is it like `file('intro.txt')[5]`?

Comment: To debug: in the while loop i would save the result to a variable as in: $line = fgets($handle); and then use a 'var_dump' statement of: var_dump($count, $line); to see what is happening and ensure the 'loop' is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work as you expect

```
$lines = file('intro.txt');
echo $lines[5];
```

Or for the fifth line:

```
echo $lines[4];
```

Comment: Huh... It says `hey user`, I expected `hello user`, which is on the fifth line. Is it because we have to subtract one from the index since arrays start at zero?